# Compare Day with day and find Next date of Day in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, if-statement

I'm working with dates in php and I'm a little stumped

This is my code:

```
$day = 'Thursday';
$i = 0;
$o_date = new DateTime("2012-09-12 20:56:43 +18 hours");
$date = date_format($o_date, 'l');
$full = date_format($o_date, 'd-m-Y');
if($day!=$date) {
    $date = new DateTime($date . " +1 days");
    $i++;
}
$order_day = new DateTime($full . " +".$i." days");$order_day = date_format($order_day, 'D, d M');
return $order_day;
```

This is what I want it to do:

1) I've got a day in string format (eg. Thursday)

2) I've got an order date (eg. `2012-09-12 20:56:43`)

I want to get that date and turn the day into a string (eg `date_format($o_date, 'l');` so that will return `Wednesday`, I then want to count how many days until the next Thursday after the order date, which I've built an if loop for. I then want to get the original date and add the amount of days the `$i` has accumulated, then return the date in day format (eg. `Thursday, 13 September`, but for some reason my code isn't working. Can someone see what I've done wrong here?

Comment: A. You need to loop through and not just increment `$i` once. B. You can use `'N'` instead of `'l'` in `date_format()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a loop, why don't you use the numeric day and calculate:

```
$day = 'Thursday';
$day_names = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
$day_num = array_search($day, $day_names);
$o_date = new DateTime("2012-09-12 20:56:43 +18 hours");
$o_day_num = $o_date->format('w');
$day_diff = ($day_num - $o_day_num) % 7;
if ($day_diff == 0) { $day_diff = 7; }
$order_day = clone $o_date;
$order_day->add(new DateInterval("P".$day_diff."D"));
```

Comment: I think this is probably a better way to go, if it fits the requirements the OP has.

Comment: Thanks but I get the following `Class 'DateTimeInterval' not found`. Plus you missed a `)` on the last line. :)

Comment: Fixed. It should be `DateInterval`.

Comment: Thanks but now I'm getting the following error? `Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`. I've tried converting it to a string with no luck

Comment: I've added a check for it already being Thursday it will go to the next week.

Comment: @Barmar thanks I've added the following line which works `return $order_day->format('D, d M');` but it's not checking the same day thing though

Comment: Not sure what happened to my edit, but I just put it back. But it's so simple, why couldn't you do it yourself?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for that. Yea I just clicked to that. Was really obvious. Sorry long day coding. Thanks so much for all your help. :D

Comment: For future reference, I've just discovered the results returning a negative, so the if statement needs to be changed to `if($day_diff<0){$day_diff=7+$day_diff;}elseif($day_diff==0){$day_diff=7;}`

Comment: I don't see how it could return a negative, since I used `% 7` to get it to 0-6.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure. It wasn't working so I did an echo and it returned a negative result. It works now though so thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

So I actually like @Barmar's idea better, but this is what I came up with... there were a number of issues in your original code, including formatting of the initial date, and the fact that you are creating a new object each time instead of working with the same one.

If you choose to use a loop, and I'm not sure you should... try this:

```
<?php
$day = 'Thursday';
$i = 0;

// Order Date
$o_date = new DateTime("2012-09-12 20:56:43 +18");
$date = $o_date->format('l');

while($day!==$date) {
  $date = $o_date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('l');
  $i++;
}
$order_day = $o_date->format('D, d M');
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, the only thing I need which I forgot to mention was if it's already Thursday that it will count to the next Thursday etc?

Comment: Yes, I figured you'd want that... honestly, I think @Barmar had the right idea, looping isn't really needed, just a little Math...

Comment: Thanks for your help though. I'm a newbie with playing with the dates part of PHP. :)