# Call to undefined method DateTime::add() - PHP Version 5.4.6

Tags: php, undefined, dateinterval

I've got the following function which I had help building at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400154/compare-day-with-day-and-find-next-date-of-day-in-php/12400494)

```
function nextDelivery($day,$o_date,$oc) {
    $day_names = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
    $day_num = array_search($day, $day_names);
    $o_date = new DateTime($o_date);
    $o_day_num = $o_date->format('w');
    $day_diff = ($day_num - $o_day_num) % 7;
    if($day_diff<0){$day_diff=7+$day_diff;}elseif($day_diff==0){$day_diff=7;}
    if($oc==2){$day_diff+7;}
    $order_day = clone $o_date;
    $order_day->add(new DateInterval("P".$day_diff."D"));
    return $order_day->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Now I've just changed my time stamp to Pacific/Auckland, as my host was America/Denver. This has changed everything except for files run using Cron Jobs, they are still outputting the old timestamp. Now if I run this function on a page in my site it woks fine, but if a cron job file, using the exact same function runs I get the following error

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DateTime::add() in ***** on line 156`

which is `$order_day->add(new DateInterval("P".$day_diff."D"));`

This is my info http://www.dpdesignz.co.nz/homefresh/lib/php_info.php

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Comment: Check DateTime module is enabled in PHP.

Comment: @zerkms, sorry please see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DateTime::add` was added in PHP 5.3.0.](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) Your cron job is probably using an older version. Try to upgrade, or change the version it uses. If you can't do that, then, as mentioned in the notes: [`DateTime::modify` is an alternative](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php).

Comment: as mentioned I'm using PHP Version 5.4.6. It works if I run it from one page, the exact same function with the exact same variables, but when the cron runs it from another page it gives me the error

Comment: But he says the script works when run as a web page, so it doesn't sound like a version issue.

Comment: @dpDesignz: Would you happen to be running multiple versions of PHP concurrently? Is the cronjob using the wrong one?

Comment: @dpDesignz: how does cron run it? as a CLI? `php -v`?

Comment: @qwzjk as far as I know my entire site is running 5.4.6. I can't find any folders that aren't

Comment: @zerkms I'm running using the default Bluehost Cron Job setup

Comment: @dpDesignz: "default Bluehost Cron Job setup" --- isn't helpful at all. Use `phpinfo();` in your script that fails to check the exact version

Comment: "as far as I know my entire site is running 5.4.6" -- how your site (that is served by web server) related to "default Bluehost Cron Job"? Why do you think they share the same php version?

Comment: @zerkms I added a bit that told me the php version it's running and it says PHP 5.2.17, so I need to find out what php file it's running from. I used the cPanel Cron Job Builder to create my cron job so I'm not sure sorry.

Comment: @dpDesignz: ok. Probably you need to contact the provider to ask why the hell they don't provide consistent software versions

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for the help. Looks like my cron job isn't being run from my profile php.ini so will contact them for support. :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP uses a different php.ini file depending on whether it's running from the CLI or as a CGI from the webserver. It sounds like the CLI php.ini may be pointing to something incorrect.

Comment: How `php.ini` is related here?

Comment: I think you may be right. I changed my line to `$order_day->modify('+'.$day_diff.' day');` and it worked, but I also added a bit that told me the php version it's running and it says PHP 5.2.17, so I need to find out what php file it's running from

Comment: Sounds like your problem is related to qwzjk's answer, not mine. Check your $PATH, maybe it's finding an old version of PHP. Also, remember that cron doesn't run your .profile, so it doesn't get any $PATH customizations you normally make.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Looks like my cron job isn't being run from my profile php.ini so will contact them for support. :)

Comment: Cron isn't supposed to run your profile. If you want your profile to be run, you have to do it explicitly, e.g. `. .profile; php scriptname`.